# counting class using jquery then multiply the value to the width for the class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need some help on how to set the width of my wrapper on how many class does my content have.

i have some fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/6cjxg654/33/) that gets the value of the class but i dont know how to implement it to make my width multiply on how many does the class matches.

```
CONTENT: 
<div id='myDiv'>
    <img src='' class='class' />
    <img src='' class='class' />
    <img src='' class='class' />
</div>
 <img src='' class='class' />


CSS:
#myDiv { width: 200px; border: 1px solid red; height: 200px; }
.class { width: 200px; border: 1px solid blue; height: 200px; }


SCRIPT:
var numItems = $('#myDiv .class').length;
alert(numItems);
```

now what I need to do is for every .class that is there on the content. I need to multiply it to the width of the #mydiv.in this case i need a 600px width for the #myDiv css

--Update

I now have the counting query the problem is its working on the fiddle but when i transfer it to my local it doesn't work.

FIddle [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/6cjxg654/38/)

Comment: $("#myDiv").css("width", (numItems * 200)); is too hard?

Comment: if you dont know how to jquery i guess?

Answer (score 2):

```
var numItems = $('#myDiv .class').length; //get the number of .class in #myDiv
var orig_width = $('#myDiv').width(); //get the original width of #myDiv
//use .outerWidth() here when you want to include padding and border
var new_width = numItems*orig_width; //multiply it with the number of .class

$('#myDiv').css('width', new_width+'px'); //set the new width to #myDiv
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bkuxdLj4/)

**Reference**

[.width()](http://api.jquery.com/width/)

[.outerWidth()](http://api.jquery.com/outerWidth/)

[.css](http://api.jquery.com/css/)

Comment: Your orig_width is targeting the wrong div. It should be the 200px from the .class div's so get $("#myDiv .class:first").outerWidth().

Note, the outerwidth is better since padding and borders will be ignored when you use width();

Comment: i did some js with my code seems to work on the fiddle but on my local the multiplier doesnt work.

Fiddle here - http://jsfiddle.net/6cjxg654/35/

Comment: @MathijsSegers OP said `I need to multiply it to the width of the #mydiv` so it should be correct here and I mentioned the difference between `.width()` and `.outerWidth`, it depends on the use-case which to use.

Comment: @MichaelPon have you included jQuery in your document ?

Comment: @empiric no he didn't he also didn't specify what should be resized or what it should be based on though.

So really his question is just unclear.

Comment: @empiric Yes. the first four lines are the counting the rest is the Jquery thing. My local files doesnt compute the width it just stay as the css

Comment: there where no errors. the width doesnt change still the same what the css width is.

Comment: i think the problem is the var numItems = $('#slider-wrapper .slide').length; it didnt count my slide inside the content i checked it using the alert(numItems); it says 0